# Connecting a dialog button to a MainWindow slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++14

I have a `Dialog` window that is supposed to be able to pass an `int` from a `QSpinBox` and an `ObjectType` from an enumerated list `enum ObjectType {FASTBALL, ODDBALL, END}` to a `MainWindow` slot. I've created and opened the dialog window in the cosntructor of the `MainWindow` with

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(ObjectController* controller, QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow), engine_(controller)
{

ui->setupUi(this);
Dialog dialog(this);
dialog.exec();

QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
view_ = new QGraphicsView(this);
view_->setScene(scene);
ui->gridLayout->addWidget(view_);
scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, VIEW_WIDTH, VIEW_HEIGHT);
connect(ui->startButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
        this, &MainWindow::startOrStop);
connect(ui->exitButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
        this, &MainWindow::close);
connect(&dialog, &Dialog::drawObjects,this,&MainWindow::spawnObjects);


// Set timer
timer_ = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer_, &QTimer::timeout,
        this, &MainWindow::moveObjects);

timer_->setInterval(CLOCK_MS);
```

}

On the `Dialog : public Qdialog` side I have a `QPushButton acceptButton_;` connected to an `accept` slot defined in the same class. The dialog also has private fields

```
int nOfObjectsToBeDisplayed_;
ObjectType objectType_;
```

and a `void drawObjects(int amount, ObjectType type);` signal.
The `accept` slot from `QDialog` is redefined as follows:

```
void Dialog::accept()
{    
  emit drawObjects(nOfObjectsToBeDisplayed_, objectType_);
}
```

Now comes the annoying part. On the `MainWindow` side, I'm trying to pass the current state of the `Dialog` to a slot `void spawnObjects(int count, ObjectType type);` with

```
connect(&dialog, SIGNAL(drawObjects(int, ObjectType)),this,SLOT(spawnObjects(int, ObjectType)));
```

This has no effect, however. The slot is not called, which I know since in its definition there is a `qDebug() << "Count: " << count << "  Type: "  << type;` line, that should print the passed object amount and the object type to the console.

Why is the slot in the `MainWindow` not being called in this case, even though it seems to be connected to it?

Comment: try with: `connect(&dialog, &Dialog::drawObjects, this, &Other_Class::spawnObjects);` and provide a MRE

Comment: It is a good idea to give signals passive names describing what they are signalling. Slots (and any non-signal function really) are then in active voice describing that they do. Makes `connect`s a whole lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so the problem was with me connecting the `Dialog::drawObjects` signal to the slot in the `MainWindow` *after* the dialog was displayed with `dialog.exec();`. This should have been obvious, but of course the dialog window can't be aware of any connections made after it is already started inside its own event loop.